# Soon as website opens, is there a way for the phone number on the site be automatically dialed?

Tags: html

Putting together a marketing for someone and he would like the number on his site automatically dialed simultaneously soon as his site is visited from a marketing link.

Is anyone aware of a way to get this done?

Call now @ (555) 555-5555 has to still be clicked on the site, an extra step so it won't work. But can this be modified somehow to launch automatically upon site visit?

Thanks

Hey everyone. Thanks for the comments and feedbacks. I greatly appreciate it. 
I just wanted to make some clarifications. For example: A plumber has an ad online and a local residence came across his ad, liked it and wanted to use his service.

Soon as prospective customer visit his site it also activates the dial pad with his local phone number, but NOT dial out so people will have a chance to cancel the call. Plumber just want people to Act and use his service soon as they visit his site, so they don't change their mind and search for other plumbers. I hope this makes sense. Thanks all.

Comment: Hopefully it is not possilbe. That would open up many possibilities for fraud.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very wise idea and probably isn't possible (at least I hope not), what is to stop somebody creating a website to force users to call a premium rate number?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible for a computer to dial a telephone number. Also, I think calling automatically upon opening the page would be a violation of users' rights.

You can definitely create a click-to-call button.
https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-general/how-to-make-a-click-to-call-button-for-your-website

Answer (score 0):

No.

It would be positively dangerous if simply visiting a website could make the user's client dial a phone number.

Premium rate phone scammers would be delighted.

Answer (score 0):

Strange question but try this, will only work on a calling device i guess.

```
<a href="tel:+005555555555" class="call">Call us</a>
```

Using jQuery or javascript to fire a click action on this when the page is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".call").trigger('click'); 
});
```

But I highly doubt that devices would let this run, otherwise that would be nuts. Imagine the security issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this](https://webcall.me) app today, you can add a link to your page and visitors will be able to call you on your mobile phone even from desktop computes

Redirect your customers to https://webcall.me/[YourName] and yor phone will ring

you have to install an app before, check out https://webcall.me/